# How to return 1 if x*x can fit in a 32-bit integer, and 0 otherwise?

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am working on a question and I am supposed to write a method  that 
returns 1 if x*x can fit in a 32-bit integer, and 0 otherwise. 

 
I thought that I could check if the number is larger than 46340 ( square root of the largest number that can be represented using 2's complement binary representation.) However I can't because I am limited to use upmost 255.

```
 /*
 * squaredOK - Return 1 if x*x can 
fit 
 in 
 a 32-bit integer, and 0 otherwise.
  *  Examples: squaredOK(10) = 1
 *            squaredOK(1000000) = 0
 *  Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + - << >>
 *  Max ops: 20
 */
int squaredOK(int x) {

return ; /* no idea */
}
```

Okay after reading the comments I decided to add the limitations:
use ONLY the following:

- Integer constants 0 through 255 (0xFF), inclusive. You are not allowed to use big constants such as 0xffffffff.
- Function arguments and local variables (no global variables).
- Unary integer operations ! ~
- Binary integer operations & ^ | + << >>

Comment: Hint: What's the square root of the `INT_MAX` value?

Comment: Also, the assignment is **ill-conceived**, the correct way to do this is to check `-46340 <= x <= 46340`. The operators that you're allowed to use cannot really do this portably, thus the answer requires some very bad implementation-specific bit-twiddling

Comment: If you can't use larger constants then just use small constants and `<<` and `|` to make larger ones.

Comment: So are `>` and `<` allowed? or just `>>`?

Comment: (a) Can `INT_MAX` be used? (b) Can comparison operators like `<` be used? (c) Is the question whether *x* • *x* fits in a theoretical 32-bit two’s complement integer or whether *x* • *x* fits in the `int` type in the C implementation it is running in? (d) Can subtraction, division, and multiplication be used? (“Binary integer operations.”)

Answer (score 0):

According to the code comment, `<<` and `|` are allowed, so you could just produce a bigger constant using shift and or.... This is simpler when converting the number to hex:

```
 46340 == 0xb504 == (0xB5 << 8) | 0x04
```

This doesn't fully solve the problem, as you don't seem to have comparison available (this restriction was added later).

In this case, I'd expect this problem to be for unsigned integers. Here, you just need to check if any of the 16 high bits is set. Fortunately, `!` is in the list of permitted operations, so you can just apply not to the number shifted to the right by 16.

If the problem is actually for signed numbers, it's more tricky. You could use `-` and a check for the sign bit to replace the comparison operator:

```
int squaredOK(int x) {
   return (x - ((0xB5 << 8) | 4)) >> 31 
}
```

To be extra safe, you could apply a double not (!!) to guard against implementation specific behavior of right shift with signed numbers.

Comment: I thought it would be trivial after this step until I realized that comparison is not available. I have extended the answer accordingly.

Comment: There are 2 problems: you need to subtract `46340` is off by one for the negative test and there is a missing `;`. Furthermore, you must convert the expression to unsigned for `>> 31` to have defined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is vaguely defined, and I think you've interpreted it in a way that's making it harder for yourself than it needs to be.

If you interpret "fit in a 32-bit integer" as an **unsigned** 32-bit integer, the square root of the maximum value (2<sup>32</sup>) has a much more convenient value (2<sup>16</sup>). I'm pretty certain this is what was intended.

Comment: I am not sure this should be an answer. “The problem was misinterpreted” is more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement `abs(x) < 46341` (or `0xb505`) with some silly limitations.

This question seems quite difficult for signed 32-bit `int`, and even harder for plain `int`.

If the question was misformulated and applies to 32-bit unsigned ints, here is a solution:

```
 /*
  * squaredOK - Return 1 if x*x can fit in a 32-bit integer, and 0 otherwise.
  *  Examples: squaredOK(10) = 1
  *            squaredOK(1000000) = 0
  *  Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + - << >>
  *  Max ops: 20
  */
int squaredOK(uint32_t x) {
    return !(x >> 16);
}
```

If the question really applies to 32-bit signed `int` with two's complement representation, you can verify that this works for all values:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int squaredOK(int32_t x) {
    return !(x + 0U >> 31) & x - (0xB5 << 8 | 5U) >> 31 |
           x + 0U >> 31 & !(x + (0xB5 << 8 | 4U) >> 31);
}

int main() {
    long long x;
    for (x = INT32_MIN; x <= INT32_MAX; x++) {
        if (squaredOK(x) != (x * x <= INT32_MAX)) {
            printf("failed on %lld\n", x);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Explanation:

```
x < 46341 && x > -46341
(x >= 0 && x < 46341) || (x < 0 && x > -46341)
(x >= 0 && x - 46341 < 0) || (x < 0 && x + 46340 >= 0)
(x >= 0 && x - (0xB5<<8|5) < 0) | (x < 0 && x + (0xB5<<8|4) >= 0)
(!(x+0U>>31) & (x - (0xB5<<8|5U)) >> 31) | ((x+0U>>31) & !((x + (0xB5<<8|4U)) >> 31)
```

Testing the sign bit by converting to `unsigned` and shifting right 31 places.
Conversion to `unsigned` is implicit of one of the operands is unsigned, hence `x + 0U` converts `x` to an unsigned type. A similar trick is used for the other expressions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil But `x` can't be "negative" - it's `uint32_t`.

Answer (score -1):

*Answer assumes unsigned, modify for your specific homework*

If any of the bits are set on the third or forth byte then you cant fit it, so your teacher wants something like:

```
          //check the third byte for bits      //check the 4th byte for bits
retbool = (((unsigned char)(x >> 16) & 0xFF) | ((unsigned char)(x >> 24) & 0xFF)));
```

If any bits in those bytes are set then you can not fit the square in the 32 bit int.  If the question was about unsigned int 32 this would be the end, but with the sign bit you have to do some checking on the second byte as well since 0xFFFF * 0xFFFF is more than max signed int.

Since you can never *really* have a negative square the unsigned version should be an alternative answer, but i didnt write this assignment.

**EDIT (if the bit patter is unique you have to mask...)**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int doesFit(int x);

typedef unsigned char uchar;
typedef unsigned short ushort;

#define MAX_POS_SQUARE 46340
#define MAX_NEG_SQUARE -46340

int main(void) {
    int x=MAX_NEG_SQUARE -2;
    int fits = -1;
    int prevoiusly_fit = 0;
    for(;x<MAX_POS_SQUARE+5;x++){
        fits = doesFit(x);
        if(!fits && prevoiusly_fit){
            printf("%d didnt fit and %d did\n",x,x-1);
        }
        else if(fits && !prevoiusly_fit){
            printf("%d fit and %d did not\n",x,x-1);
        }
        prevoiusly_fit = fits;
    }
    return 0;
}

int doesFit(int x){
    uchar bits_left = 16;
    ushort pos_mask = ((0xb5 << 8) | 0x04);
    ushort neg_mask = ((0xb5 << 8) | 0x05);
    ushort x_16_low = (((-x) & 0xff << 8 ) | (-x) & 0xff); //used in negative case
    ushort x_16_high = (-x)>>16; //used in negative case
    //Handle the negative case
    //printf("0x%04x x: 0x%04x x_16_low: 0x%04x x_16_high:", x, x_16_low, x_16_high);
    if(x>>31){
    //how can you tell if a value x < -46340
        if( (x_16_high & 0xFF) | (x_16_high >>8 & 0xFF)){
            //doesnt fit, maybe dont use compliment use ! if accidental promotion occurs
            printf("bailing out when x=%d\n", x);
            return 0;
        }
        while(bits_left){
            --bits_left;
            if(x_16_low & (1 << bits_left)){
                if(!(neg_mask & (1 << bits_left))){
                    return 0;
                }
            } 
            else if(!(x_16_low & (1 << bits_left))){
                if(neg_mask & (1 << bits_left)){
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            //high bits matched with max value bits, cant tell yet, keep masking.
        }
    }
    else{ //handle the positive case
        //how can you tell if a value x > 46340
        if( (x >> 16 & 0xFF) | (x >>24 & 0x7F)){
            //doesnt fit, return false
            return 0;
        }
        while(bits_left){
            --bits_left;
            if(x & (1 << bits_left)){
                if(!(pos_mask & (1 << bits_left))){
                    return 0;
                }
            } 
            else if(!(x & (1 << bits_left))){
                if(pos_mask & (1 << bits_left)){
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            //high bits matched with max value bits, cant tell yet, keep masking.
        }
    }
    return 1; //Must be the exact size to fit to get to this return
}
```

Output:

-46341 fit and -46342 did not

46341 didnt fit and 46340 did

I feel like i just wasted an hour of my life doing this guys homework...

Comment: The question is for signed (as evidenced by the mention of two’s complement and 46340 for the square root), but this answer is for unsigned. This answer does not answer the question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  This is the general idea to solve his homework, he can adapt it and test it for his specific purpose.  Im not gonna finish his assignments for him.

Comment: It is not a general idea that is usable, as it works only for even numbers of value bits, and a signed 32-bit integer has an odd number of value bits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ok i updated it with masking since the bit pattern is not consistent.  It passes for the relevant range of values.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  Can you explain why the edited comment is still deserving of your down vote?

Comment: (a) The new code says −46341 fit, but (−46341)**2 = 2,147,488,281, which exceeds maximum signed 32-bit integer, 2,147,483,647. (b) `-x` is undefined due to overflow when `x` is −2,147,483,648 and `int` is 32-bit. (c) `(-x)>>16` is implementation-defined when `x` is positive. (d) `x>>31` is implementation-defined when `x` is negative. (e) The question is poorly posed, but use of `while` may not conform to the intended specification and is unnecessary.

Comment: Also, “Since you can never really have a negative square the unsigned version should be an alternative answer” does not make sense. The fact that squares are non-negative does not eliminate the need to test negative inputs.